# Who to choose between husband or parents?

Tags: parents, children, husband

My husband and I had issues which led to separation for 8 months. My husband has apologised for his mistakes and wants me back. My parents are against that although I have forgiven him. Who should I choose between husband and parents? If I go with my husband and not divorce him, my parents are not going to keep terms with me. I have explained them to my level best. Who should I choose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I side with my parents or my husband?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5411/should-i-side-with-my-parents-or-my-husband)

Comment: tl;dr choose youself. If they want you then they're to live with you regardless of whom you're with. They can't have you then disagree with your parents or husband. No one should dictate anything to you. But if your husband hasn't divorced then you're still bound to him. It's tough situation. And you're always bound to your parents. If you're strong and show both parties that the other party cares then things can work over time. Don't expect immediate results. It could take 1-5 yrs. But let each side know if certain situations are met, then you're to change your approach towards them.